# Is there a way to enable proxy-protocol on Ingress for only one service?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have this service that limits IPs to 2 requests per day running in Kubernetes.
Since it is behind an ingress proxy the request IP is always the same, so it is limiting he total amount of requests to 2.

Its possible to turn on proxy protocol with a config like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
data:
  use-proxy-protocol: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
```

But this would turn it on for all services, and since they don't expect proxy-protocol they would break.

Is there a way to enable it for only one service?

Comment: looks like it's not supported in annotation, in that case deploying two ingress controller with different class name would be easy.

Comment: why you want to limit request at service level when you can limit that in the ingress? `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 12.34.56.78/32,12.34.560.78/32` and for rate limit https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-service-mesh/tutorials/ratelimit-walkthrough/

Comment: @Adiii because I don't want to limit the whole website, but only the use of one button on the site.
Sounds like it could be possible with your suggestion though. 
But when the button is blocked, I want a popup with the error and not some sort of access denied site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to configure Ingress so that it includes the original IPs into the http header.

For this I had to change the service config.
Its called `ingress-nginx-ingress-controller`(or similar) and can be found with `kubectl get services -A`

```
spec: 
   externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

And then configure the ConfigMap with the same name:

```
data:
  compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
```

Restart the pods and then the http request will contain the fields  `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Real-Ip`.

This method won't break deployments not expecting proxy-protocol.

Comment: Why to use `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`? The main reason why to use proxy protocol is to preserve the IP, but using `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` alone preserves the IP. Could you explain this please?

Comment: I don't really know why I did it this way. I remember finding a tutorial which used both.
If my memory is correct I did leave it out at first, which did not work.

Comment: I think it works for you not because of using the forwarded header, but the policy local.